# Learning Lambda Function in C++, getting "error: expected expression"

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm just learning what lambda functions are in C++ and I'm coming across an error in one I've pulled from a textbook. Since I've just started learning what they are, I have no idea what to do :/

This is the function in question:

```
void DisplayNums(vector<int>& DynArray)
{
    for_each (DynArray.begin(), DynArray.end(), [](int Element) {cout << Element << " ";} ); // lambda

    cout << endl;
}
```

And this is the error:

```
error: expected expression
        for_each (DynArray.begin(), DynArray.end(), [](int Element) {cout << Element << " ";} );
```

As far as I know, a lambda function is: [optional parameters](parameter list){ statements; }

And for my optional parameters, I left them blank...so what did I do wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using a C++11 compiler, and enabling C++11 support if necessary? How to do that depends on the compiler version, so let us know what that is if you can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Did you forget to `#include <algorithm>` ?

Comment: Mike Seymour, I don't know what version of C++ I'm using. Just scripting through SublimeText. How can I check? @inetknght I did put "#include <algorithm>"

Comment: Try this: http://www.thefourtheye.in/2013/07/Compiling-Cpp-11-Programs-with-Sublime-Text-3.html Check if it is Sublime Text 3 that you are using.

Comment: @MKII I'm using ST2. After your comment, I think it might be my text editor that is the problem and I search for an answer around that. Thanks!